# Why isn't this closing the CallableStatement?

Tags: java, jdbc

HibernateCallableStatement implements AutoCloseable so it should be closed once the try/catch is finished.  Why would this be leaving the connection open even though the CallableStatement is being passed to a try with resources block in another class?

```
protected CallableStatement fetchCallableStatement() throws SQLException {
    HibernateCallableStatement hcs = new HibernateCallableStatement(this.getDBPackageStatement().getStatement());
    this.cs = hcs.getCallableStatement();
    for (Param param : getLoadedPackageStatement().getParams()) {
        if (param instanceof In) {
            this.cs.setObject(param.getPosition(), param.getValue());
        } else {
            this.cs.registerOutParameter(param.getPosition(), (int) param.getValue());
        }
    }
    this.cs.execute();
    return this.cs;
}    

try (CallableStatement cs = this.fetchCallableStatement()) {
        //CallableStatement Building...
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CursorFetcher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: You aren't closing the `HibernateCallableStatement` but only the wrapped `CallableStatement`. Also closing the `Statement` doesn't mean the connection that originated from needs to be closed, maybe you want to execute more statements. Closing the statement isn't an indication you are done with your DB operations.

Comment: How can I close the original HibernateCallableStatement away from where it is being instantiated?  I am trying very hard to remove all of the duplicated boilerplate associated with CallableStatements by isolating responsibilities, but am having such a tough time passing around a CallableStatement object.

Comment: I have no idea what `HibernateCallableStatement` or why you even use it to execute a statement instead of regular JDBC.